# Android multiple version support : specific version folder error

Tags: android, eclipse, version

I'm trying to make custom Notifications in Android, following that link :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

This tutorial explain that we need two files for styling notification :  values/styles.xml and values-v9/styles.xml. 
(I develope on api level 7)

The second file must contain things like

```
<style name="NotificationText" parent="android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent" />
```

But with this, eclipse doesn't allow me to compile : "Error retrieving parent for item : no ressource that matches the given name 'android:...' "

Everythings is okay when I changed the API level to 9.

Did I missed something in Android multi-version programming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target API level 9 but set the minimum API level to 7.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```